# Word for the sensation between a body part being numb and the pins and needles

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a word, at least a concise description of the sensation that happens AFTER a part of your body "falls asleep".

After the total lack of sensation and control in it, but before the stinging of the pins and needles, there's an aggressive, vile sort of agony as it regains sensation that can be more unbearable than the stinging that follows.

That's something I'm trying to describe, especially as a sensation felt throughout the entire body continuously that isn't exactly just fatigue or numbness. I've considered "malaise" but it's too vague.

Comment: Very acute observation, Alex (the pun just happened, sorry), but I think you might be better asking on a medical website. But I think this cannot be considered off-topic here as being too peripheral / niche. See if anyone can answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know the feeling you are talking about, it's a deep intense ache. I don't know if there is a word for it specifically, but I wish there was! Paraesthesia is the medical term which includes numbness, tingling, pain, burning, cold, and pins and needles.

Comment: Good one!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia